# Why did Imaizumi have a 1:50 start delay on day 2 of the Interhigh?

Tags: yowamushi-pedal

In episode 31 of Yowamushi Pedal, we get to see a screen that gives the finish times of the top five finishers on day 1 of the Interhigh:

[image: ep31 13:02]

The fifth line on that display gives Imaizumi's time as "+1.55". This means "1.55 seconds after first place", right? It wouldn't make sense if it were "1 minute and 55 seconds after first place", given how close behind the first-placers he and Arakita were riding.

So in episode 32, while they're waiting at the start line to begin day 2 of the Interhigh (around 17:10 in the episode), Tadokoro tells Onoda that Imaizumi will start 1 minute and 50 seconds after the day 1 first place finishers. (This isn't a subtitling error; Tadokoro says １分５０秒後 = "1 minute and 50 seconds later".)

Based on Tadokoro's explanation of how the Interhigh works, I would've expected Imaizumi's start to be just 1.55 seconds delayed. Why was the time delay actually 1 minute and 50 seconds instead? (Even if I misinterpreted the reading on the screen, it should still be 1:55, not 1:50.)